# Ruby logger loses formatting

Tags: ruby, logging

I have a ruby console application. When I check it in irb on my dev machine, it logs ok. But when I run it in VM ruby logger loses formatting, i.e. it logs only message, without date and severity. Now this is solved by setting formatting with `Logger.formatter = proc { |severity, datetime, progname, msg| ...}`. But I'm curious as to why that could happen? I googled and found rather old info that this could happen in Rails application. Is this a known issue? It took me some time to debug this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you `require`ing different gems in the different environments, or could it be IRB itself that sets the log format? What happens if you add `require 'irb'` to your application, does that also change the formatting?

The formatting is stored in a global variable, any gem can override it. I've been bitten by a similar issue when I `require`d a gem that in turn `require`d ActiveRecord, which set the log format.

It just shows how bad it is to use global variables for configuration, something that is way too common in Ruby gems.

Comment: Right on the money! I was 'require'-ing 'active_support/core_ext' because I was using some helper methods, namely 'classify' and 'constantize'.

Answer (score 1):

FYI in Rails 3, this has changed and it's not a Class method anymore but an instance method.
So that it's not shared between all instances and gems shouldn't interfere your loggin preferences anymore.

This means that Rails 3 requires this code to change formatting for an only logger instance:

```
log = Logger.new('file.log')
log.formatter = proc { |severity, datetime, progname, msg| ...}
```